# How to use grep function to separate multiple column with common name in R?

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

For the following data set, I would like to separate columns with `beta1` only.

```
mydata
         beta1_C1 beta2_C2 beta1_C2 beta2_C1 beta3_C1 beta4_C2 beta4_C1 beta21_C1 beta21_C2 beta10_C1
    [1,]        1        9       17       25       33       41       49        57        65        73
    [2,]        2       10       18       26       34       42       50        58        66        74
    [3,]        3       11       19       27       35       43       51        59        67        75
    [4,]        4       12       20       28       36       44       52        60        68        76
    [5,]        5       13       21       29       37       45       53        61        69        77
    [6,]        6       14       22       30       38       46       54        62        70        78
    [7,]        7       15       23       31       39       47       55        63        71        79
    [8,]        8       16       24       32       40       48       56        64        72        80
```

I am using the following code but `beta10` is showing in the output which I do not want. In my expected data, I should have only `beta1_C1` and `beta1_C2` columns.

```
 dat1=mydata[,grep("beta1",colnames(mydata))]
 dat1
         beta1_C1 beta1_C2 beta10_C1
    [1,]        1       17        73
    [2,]        2       18        74
    [3,]        3       19        75
    [4,]        4       20        76
    [5,]        5       21        77
    [6,]        6       22        78
    [7,]        7       23        79
    [8,]        8       24        80
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add underscore (`_`) in your current pattern, it will solve the issue for the data shared.

```
mydata[,grep("beta1_",colnames(mydata))]
```

However, to be more specific you can do

```
mydata[,grep("^beta1_C\\d+",colnames(mydata))]
```

This will select columns which start with "beta1_C" followed by a number.

Answer (score 2):

In `data.table`, you can use `patterns()` withing `.SDcols`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^beta1_")]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
      select(starts_with('beta1_C'))
```

Or with `matches`

```
mydata %>%
     select(matches('^beta1_C\\d+'))
```